# How to align an ion-card in middle of the screen (vertically and horizontally) for iOS and Android?

Tags: android, ios, css, sass, ionic3

How to align an ion-card in middle of the screen (vertically and horizontally)?

Debugging on iOS simulator displays the card but with more margin on the left side than the right. So not really centred. To center correctly i had to 
     `left: 47.5%`; instead of `left: 50%`

- simple ion-card

  ```
  <ion-card class="error">
      <ion-card-header class="error-header">
        <ion-icon name="error"></ion-icon>
        Error
      </ion-card-header>
      <ion-card-content class="error-body">
        Error occurred!    
      </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>
  ```
- styling in the sass file

  ```
  .error {

      transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
      top: 50%;
      left: 50%;
      position: absolute;

      .error-header {
          position: relative;
          text-align: center;
          top: 36%;
          font-size: 3.0em;
          width: 100%;
          font-weight: bold;
          color: red;
      }

      .error-body {
          font-size: 1.0em;
          text-align: center;
          position: relative;
          top: 52%;
          width: 100%;
      }
  }
  ```

Answer (score 4):

IMO check your css it should be

```
    .error {

 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
     } // close here

.error-header {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  top: 36%;
  font-size: 3.0em;
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
}

.error-body {
  font-size: 1.0em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  top: 52%;
   width: 100%;
}
```

// not here

also if don't know size of card then make position fixed like try

```
   .error {

 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: fixed;
     }
```

if you set fixed position then try

```
 .error {

 transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: -50px;
    margin-left: -50px;
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
     }
```

**OR**

better you may go through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19461564/6834114)

Comment: ionic uses scss...so the closing brace is fine

Answer (score 2):

> .error {    width: 50%;    height: auto;    margin: auto; }

Answer (score 0):

You need to add the XY co-ordinates in one line

```
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Comment: Strangely enough, on iOS simulator the ionic card is some shifted to the right (more margin on left side on ion-card than the right margin).